# Optimising a recursive SQL query that processes several million records in BQ

Tags: query-performance, data-warehouse, recursive, google-bigquery

I need help optimizing a recursive SQL query in BQ.

I have hierarchical data stored in a table as parent-child relationships, i.e

[image]

will be stored as

| parent_item_id | child_item_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |
| ... | ... |

when `parent_item_id = child_item_id` it means that this is a root node. I need to produce the following resulting table from the parent-child mapping:

| root_id | parent_item_id | child_item_id | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

To do that I first prepared separate tables for parents and children:

```
-- parents
SELECT * FROM parent_child_mapping WHERE parent_item_id = child_item_id;
```

```
-- children
SELECT * FROM parent_child_mapping WHERE parent_item_id <> child_item_id;
```

Then I created a table with root nodes only. By definition, a root node is a top-level node which means it can't be a child of any other node. To identify root nodes we can calculate the set difference between parents and children tables:

```
-- root nodes
SELECT p.* FROM parents p
LEFT JOIN children c
ON 
  p.parent_item_id = c.child_item_id
WHERE 
  c.child_item_id IS NULL
```

Finally, I prepared a recursive query:

```
SELECT
  i.root_id,
  i.parent_item_id,
  i.child_item_id
  0 AS level
FROM roots i 

UNION ALL

SELECT
  t.root_id,
  t.parent_item_id,
  t.child_item_id,
  t.level + 1,
FROM children AS i

INNER JOIN objects_tree AS t
ON 
  t.child_item_id = i.parent_item_id
```

This is the final SQL query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE

parents AS (
  SELECT * FROM parent_child_mapping WHERE parent_item_id = child_item_id;
),

children AS (
  SELECT * FROM parent_child_mapping WHERE parent_item_id <> child_item_id;
),

roots AS (
  SELECT p.* FROM parents p
  LEFT JOIN children c
  ON 
    p.parent_item_id = c.child_item_id
  WHERE 
    c.child_item_id IS NULL
),

objects_tree AS (
  SELECT
    i.root_id,
    i.parent_item_id,
    i.child_item_id
    0 AS level
  FROM roots i 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    t.root_id,
    t.parent_item_id,
    t.child_item_id,
    t.level + 1,
  FROM children AS i
  INNER JOIN objects_tree AS t
  ON 
    t.child_item_id = i.parent_item_id
)

SELECT * FROM objects_tree
```

This works perfectly on a relatively small amount of data (~100K records in parent-child mapping). However, the query will take several days to run on a bigger dataset (this is shown in the execution details in BQ web UI).

The total amount of root nodes is ~45K records, whereas the children table contains ~560K entries. I assume that the issue is here:

```
...
FROM children AS i
INNER JOIN objects_tree AS t
ON 
  t.child_item_id = i.parent_item_id
```

Would it be possible to optimize it? Would it be possible to optimize it? Maybe there is a better way to write the SQL query? Or maybe there are some BQ built-in mechanisms?

**UPD**: I managed to grab some screenshots of the execution graph:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add the actual queryplan

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure I can grab it from BQ. I mean there is no EXPLAIN statement AFAIK. There is an execution graph available, though. But I don't know if it is helpfull.